# How to test interaction with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-testing

I'm trying to get to the next page in a viewpager view in a unit test for an android application. The actionbar has tabs as well. (NB: using min API level of 11).

I have tried using:

```
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
public void testPagerUI(){
    mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mViewPager.requestFocus();
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(INITIAL_POSITION); // = 0
        }
    });
this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER);
this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT);

int currPos = mViewPagerPageChangeListener.getCurrentPage();
int currTab = mActionBar.getSelectedNavigationIndex();
assertTrue(currPos == SECOND_PAGE_POS); // Fails
assertTrue(currTab == SECOND_PAGE_POS); // Fails
```

Both asserts fail, logcat shows currPos and currTab as 0.

Any insights would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried performing a precondition test. If not then you can just add the below function before "runOnUiThread()" :-

```
 public void testPreConditions()
    {
        assertNotNull(mViewPager);
    }
```

I think it is getting failed because "mViewPager" is remaining null. The above test runs before the test starts, and makes sure that the components used in the test case are not null. In case if "mViewPager" is null then the test case would fail with the "AssertionFailedError" message. And we would know.